# How to properly setup jdk7, jre6,jre7

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, java-6

I need to setup jre6, jre7, jdk7 under my C:\PFiles\metadev\java folder.But I am confused at some points.I have 3 setup files, which are named jdk-6u29-windows-x64, jdk-6u31-windows-x64,jdk-7u3-windows-x64.Also, I have an word document which explains me how to properly setup eclipse and jdk/jre stuff.I have put eclipse under C:\PFiles\metadev.That's OK.Then, in the word document it says that I should put a folder named java, which has already included jdk1.6.0_29, with the following content:

```
    jdk1.6.0_29
-bin
-demo
-include
-jre
-lib
-sample
-COPYRIGHT
-LICENCE
-README
-register
-register_ja
-register_zh_CN
-src(zip file)
-THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME
```

After placing java folder, with jdk1.6.0_29, under C:\PFiles\metadev\; the word document says that I should setup jre6, jdk7 and jre7.

Here are the points where I am confused: Does jdk1.6.0_29 stands for jdk 6? Also what does jdk-6u29-windows-x64, jdk-6u31-windows-x64,jdk-7u3-windows-x64 setup files represent(in terms of jdk6, jdk7 etc..)? I have also thought that jre is automatically comes when I setup jdk.Should I setup jdk and jre separately?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might better put that questions to the author of the document.

Comment: Without the document it is hard to see what you are exactly trying to accomplish. If you are setting up a development environment for the company where you work, or for school the answers can probably found with the author of the document.

To answer your questions. JDK 1.6.0 is indeed JDK6 and the same goes for Java 1.7.0 and JDK7 and so on. The JDK gives you the ability to develop and run Java, so installing that one should be enough(but remember, if this is a setup at work, follow the rules!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jdk1.6.0_29 is jdk6u29

jdk is java development kit which includes jre which is java runtime environment.

If you install jdk-7u3-windows-x64 you should have what you need.